# Declaring bool variable in c on linux platform

Tags: c, variables, boolean, declaration

How to declare a variable of bool datatype in C running on Linux platform. I tried the following but its giving an error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

bool factors[1000]
void main()
{
}
```

Comment: void main()? Really?

Comment: @ClarkGaebel what is wrong with that?

Comment: @RollRoll It isn’t traditional usage.

Answer (score 39):

You simply need `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer!  I have gone for years not knowing there is a standard C header that declares these types.

Answer (score 5):

C doesn't have a `bool` type.  You could use `int` instead, using 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`.

Comment: C99 does have bool. #include <stdbool.h>

Comment: Yes, C DOES have a bool type. It's _Bool, and can be used by doing #include <stdbool.h>. Remember, C99 _IS_ C.

Comment: @Clark Gaebel: nop, it's _Bool, and if you include stdbool.h you get a  macro called bool.

Comment: I typed _Bool... it interpreted the underscore as markdown and made my thing italics =/

Comment: @Clark: So escape it with backticks `_Bool`

Answer (score 2):

If a type is not defined in your environment, you can define own types, also bool, e.g.

```
typedef enum {false,true} bool;
```

Answer (score 0):

unsigned char is generally a better choice for a bool than an int, particularly if you are going to have an array of 1000 of them. Though it implementation dependent how large an unsigned char is and how the array will be packed.

Comment: No. It's usually slower, and never faster.

Comment: You're correct that access speed will generally be a tad slower, but the importance of access speed depends on how often and in what way the array is accessed. The memory savings may be far more important. Whether you're CPU constrained or memory constrained is something to consider. My guess is that it is more likely that the difference in access speed will not be noticed but the extra memory taken up by the array will be noticed. It all depends on your use scenario.

Answer (score -3):

In C99 there is a bool type. But I wonder why you can't write your code in C++. You don't need to use all the advanced OOP features of C++. You can write "C style" code and compiling it with a C++ compiler.

Comment: +1. Sensible answer. There is little a C compiler can do that won't be accepted by a C++ compiler, the C++ compiler has neat features on top of C (like, hey, bool), and is stricter on type safety than its C counterpart. And it could be a good way to learn some neat C++ tricks (like having a C struct initialize itself via a constructor...)

Comment: C++ is not a substitute for C. See => variable length arrays, variadic macros, snprintf, designated initializes.

Comment: I won't downvote because you're new, but generally you shouldn't suggest someone change their language, even from C to C++.

Comment: I think common sense should be valid also here at stack overflow. Nowadays there isn't any reason to continue to write code in Ansi C, unless very limited and specic cases (mantain legacy code, embedded systems etc...). I thought that suggesting Khushboo (who isn't a very experienced programmer) to consider the possibility of write his code in C++ wasn't a bad idea. I'm sorry if I was wrong.